# How to design model with two, independent and optional relations to the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, nested-forms

I've got a problem with designing my `User` model and making a decent form for it. I just want to ensure myself that I'm doing it wrong :)
So it goes like this:

`User` has got two `Address`es:

- a mandatory `Address` for identification and billing,
- an optional shipping `Address` that he could fill in or leave blank

I tried like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_one :shipping_address, :class_name => 'Address', :foreign_key => 'shipping_address_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
  #validations for user
end
```

and:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validations for address
end
```

And then I make a form for `User` using `form_for` and nested `fields_for`. Like this:

```
= form_for @user, :url => '...' do |a|
  = f.error_messages
  ...
    = fields_for :address, @user.build_address do |a|
      ...
```

But then, despite that `f.error_messages` generates errors for all models, fields for `Address`es don't highlight when wrong.

Also I have problems with disabling validation of the second address when the user chose not to fill it in.

And I have doubts that my approach is correct. I mean the `has_one` relation and overall design of this contraption.

So the question:

Am I doing it wrong? How would You do that in my place?

Comment: I'd use `belongs_to` association in the `User` but then the form explodes!

Comment: where is the foreign key stored? If the `user` has the `address_id` and the `shipping_address_id` it should be `belongs_to` otherwise `has_one` (and the address `belongs_to` user).

Comment: After using `has_one` in `User` ActiveRecord wanted the `shipping_address_id` and `address_id` in Address! So i put them there. I know it's not the best idea and the whole relation is somewhat inversed right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong in your form is that it will build a new address every time the view is rendered, thus losing all validation errors.

In your controller, in the `new` action you should do something like

```
@user.build_address
```

and in your view write:

```
= fields_for :address, @user.address do |a|
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But now there's this thing with disabling `shipping` address validation when it's not filled in.